# Excel working in 1 Row at a time, combining numbers without adding

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VB and I'm having trouble with this,

I have an excel document with 30 different sheets, and each sheet contains more than 1000 rows of data.

On each sheet I want to read if there is data in **`A2, A3, A4, A5`** thru the end and if this column has data then populate column AB2 by using set variable **`TC=20, cfg=10, & BCA=50`**  then take the numbers and add to the end without adding.  like the example, ignoring rows without these variables.

Example:

```
A2 contains TC9999  AB2 should say 209999                                       
A3 contains CFG8888 AB3 should say 108888                               
A4 contains BCA11   AB4 should say 500011
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain this better, i get that you want to loop through all the sheet and check the columns, the its sounds like you want to do some type of translation of the data to get your example ... maybe 1 sample row before / after transalation

Comment: sorry, I tried to post a picture, but it wouldn't let me so I reworded the question.

Comment: IFA3 contains CFG8888 and A4 contains BCA11 then would AB3 be 108888 500011

Comment: nope, stay on one row at a time.  row 3 is cfg8888    so ab3 is 108888    row 4 is bca11   ab4 would be 500011

Comment: ok final question lol, IFA3 contains CFG8888 and b3 contains BCA11 then would AB3 be 108888 500011

Comment: there should be no other columns with the variable in them, so nope.  Only read column "A" and populate Columns "AB" with variable and number.

Comment: sorry, I see why your asking.   my typing sucks today, and my proof reading is just as bad.  sorry.  fixed now.

Comment: **1)** Add a link to a picture (as a comment or [edit] the link into the post) and I will add it to the post proper.  **2)** Regarding the `adding without adding`, you are talking about concatenation.  In VBA it is the done via the `&` operator.  `"a" & "b" = "ab"`.  Beware of the spaces surrounding the `&`.  **3)** Regarding grabbing the right part of the text, use `Mid`, `Right`, or `Left` depending on what to grab.  Probably want to use `Right` here.  **4)** There is also a `Replace` function which works as named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try and I think you will be able to figure the rest out. It could be made much better, so if speed becomes and issues let me know.

```
Sub LookCodes()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim I As Long
Dim Result As String

For Each WS In Worksheets
    WS.Range("A2").Activate
    For I = 0 To WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(I, 0)) = True Then
            Exit For
        Else
            If InStr(ActiveCell.Offset(I, 0).Value, "TC") > 0 Then
                    Result = "000000" + Right(ActiveCell.Offset(I, 0).Value, Len(ActiveCell.Offset(I, 0).Value) - 2)
                    Cells(I + 2, 28).Value = "20" & Right(Result, 4) ''Added for Comment
            ElseIf InStr(ActiveCell.Offset(I, 0).Value, "BCA") > 0 Then
                    Result = "000000" + Right(ActiveCell.Offset(I, 0).Value, Len(ActiveCell.Offset(I, 0).Value) - 3)
                    Cells(I + 2, 28).Value = "50" & Right(Result, 4) ''Added for Comment
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why `I+2` in the left hand side of `Cells(I +2, ...)`?  Also, this is begging for a `With ActiveCell` somewhere to clean up the repeats.

Comment: I+2 because you are starting a Cell A2, with I as the current Row. SO as it goes through the 3rd row is I = 1 so you need to add 2 more or you will be out of sync. You could start at A1, and have I start at 2 and eliminate this. You can try it with a "with" I never use with, but that is my style there is no cost/benefit except typing less. Like I said it could be made way better, I would put the whole column in a variable and do turn off screen up dating and some other things, but I was keeping it simple.

Comment: Ah, now I see it.  I guess `ActiveCell.Offset(I,27)` would also get you there instead of using `Cells` and `ActiveCell` together.  I also don't use `With` but it cleans things up nicely here where space is limited.  Or a line continuation on those long ones so it doesn't need the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Yeah, i agree, i mostly try to help people on here get the right answer as fast as I can, if they need it "better" that is another issue and perhaps another question, plus you never know when the boss swing by lol

Comment: one more question on this same script.  how do I make the end result always have 6 digits?   so in the example A4 is BCA11    with the script it will end up being 5011  I need to make it 500011?   but if it's BCA1125 it's only 501125.